# pandas value assignment with conditions on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to calculate the Demarker Indicator in Python. Following describes how to calculate it:

1. Choose a predetermined period “X” (Standard value is “14”, although a value of “8” or “9” tends to be more sensitive);
2. Calculate DeMax = High – Previous High if >0, otherwise DeMax = 0;
3. Calculate DeMin = Previous Low – Low if >0, otherwise DeMin = 0;
   DeM = MA of DeMax/(MA of DeMax + MA of DeMin).

Following is my attempt, `df` is a dataframe contains open high low close price with date as index:

```
df['DeMax'] = df['High'] - df['High'].shift(1)
df['DeMin'] = df['Low'].shift(1)-df['Low']
# Method 1: df['DeMax'][df['DeMax'] < 0] = 0.0 
# Method 2: df[df['DeMax']< 0]['DeMax'] = 0.0
```

If I use Method 1, it is ok. But if I use Method2, I will get warning `SettingWithCopyWarning`, even I use copy method like this `df['DeMax'] = df['High'].copy() - df['High'].copy().shift(1)` won't solve the issue.

I have also checked that `df['DeMax'][df['DeMax'] < 0]` and `df[test['DeMax']< 0]['DeMax']` are same pandas series, so why they behave differently if I try to assign values?

Also, if I do something like this

```
df['DeMax'] = df['High'] - df['High'].shift(1)
df['DeMin'] = df['Low'].shift(1)-df['Low']
a = df['DeMax'][df['DeMax'] < 0]
a = 0
```

Then `a` will be 0 instead of a pandas series, but I also expect `df['DeMax'][df['DeMax'] < 0]` will be 0, which does not happen, could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['DeMax'] < 0,'DeMax']=0 # it will change all value less that 0 to 0
```